# How to invoke companion banner ad in OpenX along with a video ad?

Tags: video, ads, flowplayer, openx

Here's the scenario :

I have installed OpenX on my server and i have added a few VIDEO ads and a few BANNER (image) ads.
Now, in OpenX, i have linked one particular Banner ad as a companion ad to one particular Video ad.
I'm using the OVA-plugin with flowplayer to call the video ads and the video ad is playing well.

However, how do i get the companion banner ad to appear when the video is playing?

I understand that there is an invocation code for every zone and i can place that code in my page to display the banner ads from that zone and this will display all the banners defined in the zone in a random manner.

However, how do i ensure that only *that specific banner that was defined as a companion to the video will be displayed* when the video is playing ?

Kindly help me out on this. I've been breaking my head to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!! Looks like i've got to read the config docs carefully!!!

For anybody else who might be searching for the same answer, here's how you do it.

In the config for the ova plugin, just add a "companions" object and define the regions where you want the banners to appear. The "id" in the region is the "id" of the  block where you want the banner to appear.

```
ova: {
     url: "/flowplayer/ova.swf",
     autoPlay: true,
       companions: {
            restore: false,
            regions: [
               { 
                   "id":"companion", 
                   "width":"300", 
                   "height":"60" 
               },
               { 
                   "id":"companion-300x250", 
                   "width":"300", 
                   "height":"250" 
               }
            ]
         },
     }
 }
```

Ref : http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/open-video-ads/13048/ova-configuration-guide/#configuring-companions

Answer (score 0):

OpenX Source Ad Server (http://www.revive-adserver.com) Companion Demo :

http://caffe.ch/media/SWF/ova.flowplayer/examples/ad-servers/example01.html

```
            "companions": [
               { "id":"companion-160x600", "width":"160", "height":"600" },
               { "id":"companion-300x250", "width":"300", "height":"250" }
            ],
```

Regards,

Chinnu.G